# Why is there non-zero probability for a particle to "escape" completely from a solid?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-tunneling, decoherence

Let's consider a particle (electron or proton) in a "macroscopic" solid.

Outside of the solid, the state of the particle would have a higher energy.

Because of the conservation of energy, quantum tunnelling takes place between two states of the same energy.

All that being said, why is there a **non-zero** (although astonishingly, fantastically, ridiculously, unimaginably etc. small) **probability** for the particle to "go out" of the solid completely?

Comment: Is the answer you seek merely the math behind such a claim?  Or are you arguing that you feel a particle should *never* be able to escape its solid, and thus the quantum claim is suspect.

Comment: The toy version of this problem, the [finite square well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well) is a standard exercise for developing this idea. You may be interested in the almost entirely unrelated phenomenon of [sublimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublimation_(phase_transition)), in which molecules escape from macroscopic solids in a way explicable in classical physics terms.

Comment: @CortAmmon It is all about Nature. Not about math or one's feelings.

Comment: Because there is a non-zero temperature to the universe.

Answer (score 1):

Because for a single subatomic particle, it is not possible to precisely pin down its location. Because of this positional uncertainty, it becomes possible for that particle to assume a location on the "wrong side" of a barrier, with a certain (perhaps small) probability of this actually happening. Wikipedia has a pretty good explanation of this process.

Comment: I really appreciate the Wikipedia reference. However, crucial aspects of the question remain untouched: quantum tunnelling occurs between two states of the same energy.

Answer (score 1):

This surprises many people, but science is not concerned with *why* nature does something.  It is concerned with how to predict it and model it.  Indeed, we can see this in the interpretations of QM.  In QM, we have a wave function, which is a mathematical construct.  It asserts that if there are two particles interacting, their behavior is well modeled by the Schrodinger wave equation.  But the Schrodinger equation is over complex numbers.  Our intuition about the world is much better captured by real numbers.  Somehow this complex-valued wave equation needs to be tied to our real-valued "world" of non-QM physics.  For this, they rely on the [Born rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule), a postulate about nature that has so far held true.

To quote [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretations_of_quantum_mechanics), all of the major QM interpretations share the same formalism (the mathematical structures used, such as the Schrodinger wave equation), and phenomenology (what can be observed by scientists).  However, neither of those describes *why* particles do what they do.  For that, one needs to look at ontology (what is claimed to be true about the world), and epistemology (what can be known about the world).  Those are the philosophical topics that surround the question "why."

And, among the interpretations, "why" varies greatly.  The Copenhagen interpretation would argue that the particle can leave the solid because, when you observe it, you collapse the waveform and the particle is found in a probabilistic location governed by Born's rule, which mathematically can be shown to include any location in the universe (at naturally low probabilities, of course). The many worlds interpretation would argue that when you observe the particle, the universe "splits" into a multiverse where each of the "you" observers across the universe sees a different measurement of the subject.  The DeBroglie-Bohem pilot wave theory would argue that there is a universe-spanning wave which perturbs the location of particles.  This wave changes with respect to an object instantaniously (faster than the speed of light), but is carefully constructed to make sure no classical information can be gleaned from it.  This wave has no bounds on how steep it can be (although higher gradients are less likely), so the wave may catapault your particle out of the solid.

All three of these offer a "why" for your question.  They decidedly do not agree, and science will never tell you one is right over the other because they all predict the exact same phenomenology (the same set of experimental results -- almost.  Since The DeBroglie-Boehm model was constructed, new experiments suggest that the "pilot wave" approach may be very hard to align with the new data.  The major interpretations, Copenhagen, Many Worlds, and modern decoherence based interpretations still hold).  We simply cannot tell you "why" using science because that is not what science was designed to do.

It does, of course, turn your query on its head, and that's where it gets interesting.  You ask "why should a particle be able to leave a solid."  I ask "why not?"  Why shouldn't a particle be able to do it?  Why should you assume that the universe is just that well ordered?  Is someone going to write it a ticket if it doesn't obey those rules?

The answer is generally along the lines of Occam's razor.  All else being equal, the simplest explanation is usually best.  The pain of Quantum Mechanics is that, through decades of observations, we had to conclude that the simplest explanation didn't work!  The culmination of thousands of years of intuition and science leads us to assumptions about how particles work that are simply wrong.  So now "all else" is no longer equal.  We have classical models, that are simple but wrong, and we have QM models that are complex but (so far) are right!

So we return to Occam's razor.  The simplest models we have for how the universe work which actually match the results of particle physics experiments all suggest there is a waveform that can be used to predict the behavior of the particles.  And, in all formulations so far, these follow simple rules which predict that a particle can theoretically jump *anywhere* in the universe when being observed.  Perhaps there is a more complicated theory which prevents such movement, but at the present we assume our "simple" QM theory (which is not so simple!) to be the best.

If you're really interested in alternate ways to think about this problem, one way I find interesting is to look at decoherence.  Modern theories are less concerned with what happens when a "classical observer observes a quantum mechanical system," and consider the possibility that our observing tools (or even ourselves!) are quantum mechanical beings themselves.  This suggests that a particle *cannot* simply be flung across the universe by observing it by arguing that a particle does not have a simple classical (x, y, z) position in the first place!  It has a quantum structure (which happens to be non-zero for nearly all positions), and that's all we say.  Decoherence has a tremendous advantage of making troublesome experiments more intuitive.  Experiments like the Delayed-Eraser double-slit experiments are terribly hard to intuit about.  They only make sense mathematically.  But they are less paradoxical feeling when you don't rely on an interpretation which assumes this perfectly classical observer is doing all of the observing.

Comment: Most excellent, +1. -Niels